# How can I make a ajax post request on jqgrid nextpage button click to load new set of data?

Tags: php, ajax, jqgrid

How can I make a ajax post request on jqgrid nextpage button click to load new set of data? I have to post id of the last row for select next set from db

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid do Ajax request automatically if you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` and you don't use `loadonce: true` option additionally.